# Extra sorting criterium in case of ex aequo with Views

Tags: views, 7

My articles have a 'Ranking' field, which contains an integer. I have a view that sorts articles depending on this value: the article with the highest score is a the top. Now, when two articles have the same amount of points, I'd like the most recently posted article to get the highest ranking.

For example. Let's say I have 3 articles:

- 'Article A' (5 points - posted on 30/12)
- 'Article B' (5 points - posted on 21/12)
- 'Article C' (6 points - posted on 20/12).

The ranking should be:

1. 'Article C'
2. 'Article A'
3. 'Article B'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new sort criteria, Posting date, set it to descending and make sure the order of your sort criterias are correct, first points, then date.

Comment: Thanks, the order of my sort criteria was wrong, so that's why it didn't work.